# Hibernate/JPA Bidirectional cascade saveOrUpdate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-4.x

I am trying to have a many-to-many bidirectional relationship for 2 entities (News and Tag).

But when I try to saveOrUpdate the News (which has Set), somehow it always saves a new set of Tag even id is already populated in the Tag

Is it something wrong with my annotation?

News.java

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "NEWS_ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,  cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @Cascade( org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE )
    @JoinTable(name = "NEWS_TAGS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "NEWS_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TAG_ID"))
    public Set<Tag> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }
```

Tag.java

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "TAG_ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    private Collection<News> news;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy = "tags")
    public Collection<News> getNews() {
        return news;
    }
```

NewsDAO

```
public void save(News news){
         this.hibernateSessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(news);
    }
```

What I want to do is when, I save "News", the related Set will be ignored if Tag exist, and will insert new if Tag isn't, is this possible?

Please advise

Comment: Is your tag objects already connected (are they hibernate connected objects)?

Comment: I can only get String from web layer, so I have to recreate the set (getting the id from the db and set it back to the Tag) before I do the saveOrUpdate on the News. Is there a way to make hibernate aware that these Tags.

Comment: Try get the object (Tag) from the db, not only the id. If you use the already connected object, it should work

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I set the set<Tag> within the news object and when I saveOrUpdate the news it worked. Please add an answer so I can close the question and you get the points ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your object (Tag) is not "connected". By that I mean hibernate is not aware of your object and, when you try to save News, hibernate will see your Tags as new Objects always. Try get the Tag object from db before save or update and use this object.